# Intent getting send again when activity resumed

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the share intent to let the user share image within my application,so when user shares an image my activity sends the image to server and shows up in app. The problem is that when user go back and resume the app again then the same intent process is happening again.

here's the intent handling code which i am calling in `onCreate()` method

```
public void handleIntents(){

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();


    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
           // handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            //handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
        }
    } else {
        // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
    }

}
```

here's the manifest declaration

```
<activity
        android:name=".HomeScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
           <!-- <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />-->
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

So,when I consumed the intent then it should not happen unless a new intent is again created.

Note: I would suggest please create the same situation,try the code on your system.

What I want is ; I share an image from gallery to this app.Now I press back then open this activity from recents,

1. It should not try to resend the image.

   When I go back and again select an image and share with my app then
   it should.

Answer (score 2):

<del>After you return to the same activity, Android will reuse the same intent to ensure same state can be achieved, try `setIntent(null)` after handling the image</del>

From your comment i think i get the use case now,
 thats happens because the activity wasn't finished so each time `onCreate` method is called because either the screen rotated or the system recreated the activity (going to background or such), `onCreate` is called and will pass you the same intent that was used to start the activity in the first time, what you can do in that case is check for the Bundle savedInstanceState that you receive on the `onCreate` method, if it is `null` then its the first time the activity is being created and you should upload the image otherwise the activity is being recreated and you don't need to upload the image.
Also because the image may or may not had be uploaded with success, the screen may rotated and the upload stoped, etc (this will depend on how you do your upload, AsyncTaks, Thread, Services etc) you may actually want to try to upload the image again, in that case you can do as @eduyayo suggests and use an extra to indicate that the image has been uploaded already

Comment: Adding to @forcewill answer, if you still wanna keep the intent for loading data from it or whatever, you can use the condition when `onCreate(android.os.Bundle)` is called with a non null Bundle, you´re reusing the previous activity so you know you have to handle it differently. Also you can set an extra to the intent for not to loose it´s data but to know it is already handled

Comment: Try this in your activity 
'@Override protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {     super.onNewIntent(intent);     setIntent(intent); }'

Comment: nope , what i am doing is go to gallery share an image with my app ; handle that intent ; press back ; and go back to app from recent task list; and it's again starts sending the image

Comment: what if my activity is running in the background and user again send an image ; it will not get sent because instance will not be null

Comment: in that case you can compare the file url in the intent with the one you're uploading or already uploaded, you could even maintain an array of images uploaded and check if the "new" one is already uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You can always overwrite what's being called on onResume().

Another idea that comes to mind now, you could use threads.And onResume, you make sure that thread won't start.How?A boolean should do the job.I will write you some pseudo-code so you can understand what I am saying.

```
Boolean name = false;

onCreate(){
  if(name = false){
          Run ur thread now
     }
}
onResume(){
  if(name = false){
          Run ur thread now
     }
}
```

That should do the job,mate.Let me know if you need more info.I'll be back later a bit.